# Any impact with changing SSL certificate from new Certificate Authority?

Tags: sharepoint-server, certificate, iis7

We are using SSL certificate for our SharePoint sites.

The present SSL certificate will be expired soon and getting the new SSL certificate with same fqdn match, but from different certificate authority.

Will it be any impact internally with SharePoint trust after installing certificate from new CA.

Should we take care any certificate private keys in IIS or SharePoint end after new certificate installation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine to get certificate from different certificate authority, while I would suggest you backup old certificate and replace it before old one expired per my experience(in case of any step error, revert it back).

The key is binding with certificate, if new certificate is configured, old key will not use anymore.

[Here](https://spramesh2010.wordpress.com/2017/11/02/sharepoint-server-renewing-ssl-certificates-quickly/) is a good thread for your reference.